# How to deploy/run app on ipad simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble converting my iphone app to the ipad. I already created a separate storyboard, and set the ipad storyboard to the new one from the build settings, however, whenever I run it on the ipad 6.0 simulator, it's not using the new storyboard I made (but still using the iphone's storyboard).

Is there some setting that I'm missing to deploy/test using the new storyboard I made for ipad?

Comment: Are you manually setting any storyboards in your AppDelegate? Or doing any manual loading of things in there of any sort?

Comment: That was it, I was calling a storyboard manually for a viewcontroller popup and forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

In **Project settings** > (select your *target*) > **Summary** tab 
You'll see **iPhone / iPod Deployment Info**, scroll down to **iPad Deployment Info** and put your storyboard in **Main Storyboard** field.

[image]

Comment: As was stated in the first post, I did this already yet it is still using the iphone's storyboard